# SaveFileDialog.ShowPinnedPlaces not available?

Tags: c#, inheritance, savefiledialog

Since SaveFileDialog inherits from System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog shouldn't it be the case that all methodes are available ?
If I create the following, its not accessible - why ?

```
using ( SaveFileDialog fHandle = new SaveFileDialog() ) { fHandle.ShowPinnedPlaces ... }
```

Addition:
Since this is .net version dependent is there a way to add a compiler directive / parser directive that will ignore it if it is less than required version of this object ( property/method ) or accept if its compatible ?

Comment: It is available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0
but it's not a method, it's a property. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I would like to avoid getting showed all pinned places in this dialog

Comment: Then you should be able to do fHandle.ShowPinnedPlaces = false.

Comment: getting this if so:   'System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog' does not contain a definition for 'ShowPinnedPlaces' and no extension method 'ShowPinnedPlaces' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)

Comment: ShowPinnedPlaces was added in .NET 7. Which version are you using?

Comment: using # 5.0 okay so that explains. Learned where to look in detail and where it is important to look at. Thank you

Comment: .NET 5 reached End Of Life a while ago and was only a short-term support version anyway. The oldest supported version is .NET 6, a Long-Term-Support version, supported until 2024. The next LTS version, .NET 8, will be released in two weeks